# Stencil Bigcommerce .scss error

Tags: node.js, sass, bigcommerce

After running $stencil init and $stencil start I get this error:

{ [Error: tools\list.scss doesn't exist!]
  formatted: 'Error: tools\list.scss doesn\'t exist!\n        on line 1 of tools/tools.scss\n>> @import "list"; \n   --------^\n',
  message: 'tools\list.scss doesn\'t exist!',
  column: 9,
  line: 1,
  file: 'tools/tools.scss',
  status: 1 }

The error occurs immediately after installation before any files are edited.
I went over the prerequisites several times and can't find anything that im missing.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you running on windows, os x, or a flavor of ubuntu?

Comment: I am also facing the same error from yesterday on windows install. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Windows 8 & 10. Same errors on both machines.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error. 
Now I am getting an error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)." on the theme.css file after I bundle and upload. Locally the theme runs perfect,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We reverted the most recent rollout to Stencil, which should unblock you from this issue. We'll work on identifying the cause to reintroduce the improved bundling support.

Doing a fresh stencil install should resolve for the time being.